# Remove section of form on hosted page

Tags: javascript

I am using Chargify to sell subscriptions online. They provide hosted pages where you can collect information that leads to the creation of a subscription and customer in their system. I'm trying to remove the "Purchase Summary" section of the signup form because it confuses my customers. Chargify allows me to add custom javascript that gets inserted right before the  tag in a  tag.

Here's my signup page: https://shopify-petit-vour.chargify.com/h/3370883/subscriptions/new

My issue is that my new subscribers are often on a waiting list, but they sign up with their first month's charge to reserve their subscription spot. It's not a "setup" fee, because it counts as their first month's payment. But if I don't call it a setup fee, the Purchase Summary says they'll be charged again in one month's time, rather than when their subscription begins. Either option Chargify gives me for the form confuses my customers. I want to remove the Purchase Summary section and explain in the product description section the details of their purchase.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following Javascript

```
$("#summary").hide();
```